# Perform segue programmatically "swift"

Tags: xcode

I added in buttons the "addTarget" property programmatically to go to another view Controller but it doesn't work.

```
login.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("toHome")), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

@objc func toHome(_ sender : UIButton!){
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Index", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the *native* selector syntax

```
login.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toHome), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and an implicit unwrapped optional as parameter is Swift 2 legacy syntax. Remove the exclamation mark

```
@objc func toHome(_ sender : UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Index", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: it's not work and this is the reason " has no segue with identifier 'Index' " , and i'm sure it's the same name in the storyboard id

Comment: The compiler is right. The storyboard ID is **not** the identifier. Select the **segue** and press ⌥⌘4 (Attributes Inspector)